# Bubble chat titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-alloy

https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/146449/how-do-i-make-a-view-with-a-bubble-but-with-a-continuous-border

I have found this tutorial, and I am trying to create a bubble chat window in titanium.

However the trouble I am having is that I cannot get the height/width of the label until I have stuck it onto the window and inside the view, even then if the label is too small, the bubble chat becomes distorted.

What is the best way to accomplish this in titanium, thanks.

```
var label1 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    color : '#999',
    text : 'I am Window 1',
    font : {
        fontSize : 20,
        fontFamily : 'Helvetica Neue'
    },
    textAlign : 'center',
    height : 'auto',
    width : 'auto',
});


var bubble1 = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundImage : 'bubble.png',
    backgroundLeftCap : 43,
    backgroundRightCap : 34,
    backgroundTopCap : 34,
    backgroundBottomCap : 36,
    height : 10,
    top : 10,
    visible: false,
    width : 10
});

bubble1.add(label1);
win1.add(bubble1);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get height/width of label use: `label1.toImage().width`  or `label1.toImage().height`

and the best way to do it is:
after adding label to View you need:

1. check width of label, if it is too long, and over fit of screenwidth then change back label width to size of screen - 50 px.  `if(label1.toImage().width > Ti.Platform.displayCaps.getPlatformWidth()) label1.width = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.getPlatformWidth() -50;`
2. Change back width of View to same width of label.
3. Set `label1.heigh = Ti.UI.SIZE`  (auto is not supported now)
4. Set `View.height = Ti.UI.SIZE`

To check small size, you can do this:

`if(Ti.Platform.displayCaps.getPlatformWidth() < 100){
   label1.width = 100;
   View.width = Ti.UI.SIZE;
}`